# TWSocket takes a while to reconnect

Tags: sockets, delphi, timer, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a `timer` with a 2 second interval. After 2 seconds, the `socket` is connected to with the below code:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  if WSocket1.State = wsClosed then
  begin
    try
      WSocket1.Connect;
    except
      WSocket1.abort;
    end;
  end
  else if WSocket1.State = wsConnected then
  begin
      //send data
  end;    
  Timer1.Enabled := true;    
end;
```

This works as intended and connects in roughly 2 seconds as expected then subsequent executions send the data.

However if I physically disconnect the device on the `socket` and reconnect it, the re-connection takes approximately 3 minutes. This is not the device as restarting the program reconnects the socket in around 2 seconds again.

I have tried changing the 2 second interval to an arbitrary number around 2 seconds, 1937 milliseconds for example, to see if this makes a difference but the issue persists.

So my question is how to I ensure this reconnects in the same amount of time, roughly 2 seconds, as it initially connects?